# how do i set style of element on content page from master page using java script

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have a div element with id "dashbmaindivision" on my content page
and i have  another element on master page which onclick runs a java script function on the master page. the function is to add css style to the div element with id "dashbmaindivision" on my content page but is not working out

the name of my content page is dashboard

```
<!--this is my java script function my on master page-->

<script type="text/javascript">

function changNav() {            

document.dashboard.getElementById("dashbmaindivison").style.backgroundColor ="red"
    }
 </script>

<!--this is my html of my master page-->

<div style="z-index:4">
     <a href="#" onclick="changNav()" id="openbtn" runat="server" style="font-size:x-large; color:white;" class="place-right"><span>&times</span></a>
    </div>

 <!--this is my html of my content page-->
<asp:content id="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<div  id="dashbmaindivison" runat="server"> </div>
</asp:content>
```

i expect that the style which is the background color of my div element with id "dashbmaindivison" on the content page would change.

Comment: Inspect whether the id 'dashbmaindivison' is available in browser Elements  tab

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `.dashboard`.

```
document.getElementById("dashbmaindivison").style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

Comment: it still did not work for me (please the script is running from the master page whilst i want the effect to take place on the content page)

Comment: Try putting the script at the bottom of the master page, before the closing body tag.

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript is not working because your div is a server side control and you need to do this as below:

```
   var myDiv = document.getElementById("<%=dashbmaindivison.ClientID%>");
   myDiv.style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

or using jquery you can do as below:

```
$('[id$=dashbmaindivison]').css("backgroundColor", "red");
```

Comment: I have tried this but now gets this error : 'dashbmaindivison' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.